Help with stars and bars
I have 2 questions, which I need to check:

How many ways can you add up 7 numbers (each >=0), so that they total to 37, but the first three numbers add up to 6.

My answer:
$C^8_6*C^{34}_{31} = 335104$
I used theorem two from the following, to find ways which 4 numbers add up to 31 and 3 numbers add up to 6 and multiplied them.

A message consists of 12 packets and 45 blank spaces (blank spaces must be between packets), each packet must have a minimum of 3 blank spaces between them, how many ways can a message be sent this way?

My answer:
$12!*C^{22}_{12} = \frac{22!}{10!}$
There are 12! factorial ways to shuffle the packets and for each combination of packets there are 12 (45-33 bcs 3 min between each packet) spaces that need to be kept in between 11 spaces(between 12 packets), so same theorem two of stars and bars ($s_1+s_2+...+s_{11}=12$).

The 2nd one depends on whether a message can start and end with spaces or not. If not, I think you are right.

@torontohrb My question says spaces are between packets. Let me add that real quick

Don't use Theorem 2 in the link you gave. It makes things unnecessarily complicated. For example, to find the number of solutions to  $x_1 +x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ with $x_i\ge 0$, we can simply add one to each variable. The problem is equivalent to $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=14$ with $y_i>0$. Right away we know the answer is $13\choose 3$.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
How many ways can you add up $7$ numbers $\in \braces{0,1,2,3,\ldots}\,$ so that they total $\mbox{to}~37$, but the first three numbers add up to $6\, ?$.
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots
\sum_{n_{7} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} = 6}
\bracks{n_{1} + \cdots + n_{7} = 37}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots
\sum_{n_{7} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{x^{6}}x^{n_{1}\ +\ n_{2}\ +\ n_{3}}\
\bracks{y^{31}}y^{n_{4}\ +\ \cdots\ n_{7}}\,\,\,
\right\vert_{\verts{x},\ \verts{y}\ <\ 1}
\\[5mm] = & \
\braces{\bracks{x^{6}}\pars{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x^{n}}^{3}}
\braces{\bracks{y^{31}}\pars{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}y^{n}}^{4}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\braces{\bracks{x^{6}}\pars{1 - x}^{-3}}
\braces{\bracks{y^{31}}\pars{1 - y}^{-4}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\braces{{-3 \choose 6}\pars{-1}^{6}}\braces{{-4 \choose 31}\pars{-1}^{31}}
\\[5mm] = & \ {8 \choose 6}\pars{-1}^{6}
{34 \choose 31}\pars{-1}^{31}\pars{-1} =
{8 \choose 6}{34 \choose 31}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{167552}}
\end{align}

oh wow I forgot to use 3! instead of just 3, so I forgot to divide by 2. Thanks for pointing it out!
